# `CoreTextEditContext::NotifySelectionChanged ` An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal

Tags: uwp

I have two questions regarding the Universal app API in `Windows::UI::Text::Core`:

1. Why doesn't pressing keys like [Enter] on the touch keyboard invoke `TextChange` event handler of `CoreTextEditContext`? (I have to handle the `KeyDown` event to capture [Enter] keys on the software input panel.)
2. Why does `NotifySelectionChanged` when inserting a new line character at the end of the text always cause crash with exception **An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal** mentioned in the title on *Windows 10 Mobile* (build 10586) while it works fine on PC? I can confirm that the new selection range is correctly computed. It feels like *Windows 10 Mobile* lacks the failsafe mechanism in the PC version.

I know that I should not ask questions about unofficial OS builds. But I want it to work well when Windows 10 Mobile is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: must do `NotifyTextChanged` appropriately.